# Check if object is anchored(Roblox Lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

I was working on my game, but I came across a roadblock. I wanted to use an if statement to detect if an object was anchored, and if it is, then the player teleports. I have tried to get this to work for hours with no luck. Any advice?

Comment: `if object.Anchored then --[[code]] end`

Comment: Quick Question, how would I check if the object's transparency was 1?

Comment: `object.Transparency == 1` would be condition for that. Everything you see in the Properties window is a property and you can access all of them using a dot like I've done. This is called indexing if you didn't know. All properties of parts are listed [here](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the part's anchored property is true and then teleport the player by setting their `HumanoidRootPart` to the part. To do this, you could do the following:

```lua
local part = workspace.Part
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer or game.Players.LocalPlayer:CharacterAdded:Wait()
-- wait for character to fully load in

if part.Anchored then
    plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position = part.Position -- teleport the player to the part
end
```